# Rewrite Rule - add not precised number of parameters to a rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

is it possible to make rule that works like this:

```
example.com/param1val/param2val/param3val/...
```

And as follow, many params. I can't know how many of them would be there, but I want to rewrite it to:

example.com/index.php?param1=param1val&param2=param2val&param3=param3val...

and so on. Is it possible in one rule?

Comment: Will these parameters always have literal **`param`** in it?

Comment: @anubhava: No, they would be various, and it's not important to make variable names the same as given in URL params. It coul'd be also index.php?a1=var1&a2=var2&a3=var3 and so on.

Comment: Since mod_rewrite cannot generate string with counter in it you have 2 options: 1) Include param names also in URL OR 2) keep param name same as param value

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment this answer is for `case 1)`:

```
RewriteEngine On

## reucrsion based rule to convert /user/n1/v1/n2/v2 to /user.php?n2=v2&n1=v1
RewriteRule ^(index\.php)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)(/.*)?$ /$1/$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Comment: This is not really what I wanted to have. For example I want that URL: 1/2/3/4 to rewrite as ?1=2&3=4 but also 1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8 rewrite as ?1=2&3=4&5=6&7=8. Is it possible in one rule or not?

Comment: Wish you had tried this on your host. As I wrote this is recursion based rule, it will work with even `/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8` OR `/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8/9/10/11/12` and so on.

Comment: Above `/index.php/1/2/3/4/5/6/7/8` will be rewritten as: `/index.php?7=8&5=6&3=4&1=2`